# Can I solve "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages." in laravel composer

Tags: laravel

[when I want to install laravel/ui the composer show this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot4tV.png)

[and my composer.json :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq7PL.png)

my laravel version is 6.13 and I went to laravel.com and I click the Authentication for laravel 6X and says for laravel 6 you have to install this package and the package is composer require laravel/ui "^1.0" --dev and composer show me that problem again what can I do?

Comment: Your dependencies are locked to their versions in composer.lock. `composer install` checks that file which versions to use you can delete that file than try again (a new file will be created) or run `composer update`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in composer.json and then use command `composer update`

```
"laravel/ui": "^1.2",
```

Sometimes the library which you're installing is not satisfied PHP version not only laravel version.